# what kind of items can add into a WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I have a WapPanel in my Xaml code.
What kind of items exactly i can add into it?

I know that I can add some Shapes to draw, but I want add and show some Lable or TextBlock with those shapes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrappanel` uses `UIElementCollection` for its children so you can add any `UIElement`

So basically you can add any 
Control (TextBox, Label etc), Shapes, Lines, pretty much anything except Windows